# when i open phone photos choose one to back app force closed with xiaomi MIUI, other phone work well. thank for your advise?

Tags: android

this is my code to open phone's photo to choose one when back app force closed and `onActivityResult()` not work.

```
Intent picture = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(picture, 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        UIUtils.printLog("onActivityResult");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0: // take photo
                    try {
                        mImageFile = FileUtils.createTempImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    FileUtils.cropImage(UploadIDCardActivity.this,
                            sFileUri, mImageFile, REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP);
                    break;
                case 1: // pick photo
                    try {
                        mImageFile = FileUtils.createTempImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    FileUtils.cropImage(UploadIDCardActivity.this,
                            data.getData(), mImageFile, REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP);
                    break;
                case REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP: // crop photp and upload
                    mCurrFile = mImageFile.getPath();
                    UIUtils.printLog("REQUEST_IMAGE_CROP");
                    try {
                        getDataImageUpload(mImageFile);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

this is monitor error , when app force closed monitor give me the error message . the error only happen whit MIUI , my phone is xiaomi5  MIUI 8.1.6.0  Android 6.0.1

```
01-02 13:16:42.291 2289-2289/? E/Icon: Unable to load resource 0x00000000from pkg=com.android.systemui
                                         android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1374)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:145)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:313)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:269)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableAsUser(Icon.java:377)
       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.ExpandedIcon.getDrawable(ExpandedIcon.java:59)
       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.getIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:174)
       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.setIcon(StatusBarIconView.java:131)
       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.StatusBarIconView.updateDarkMode(StatusBarIconView.java:266)
       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.SimpleStatusBar.updateDarkMode(SimpleStatusBar.java:233)
       at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar$26.run(PhoneStatusBar.java:3169)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5458)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the permissions. Actually there is concept of Permission Manager in XIOMI devices and you have to ask for user permission. For trial you can check the permission manager and enable the necessary permissions for your application.For more info read permissions in xiomi devices on google.

Comment: thanks your advice but in device system Permission Manager i give all permissions   of app , it still not work . and the problem don't happen every times, 30% it work ok .

Comment: It may be because when app is destroyed you can not run any service in background(if that is case) in XIOMI devices.

Comment: thank you very much, I have resolved the problem. it conflict with the third party lib umeng PushAgent. Update to the latest version , app work well .